# My code running wrong and making A instead of not answered

Tags: javascript, html, pdf, pdf-generation, web-development-server

When I pdf is generated instead of not answering it is appearing as a for this code

```js
 function generatePDF() {
  // Create a new PDF document
  var doc = new jsPDF();

    // Define an array of questions
    var questions = [
      "Question 1", "Question 2", "Question 3", "Question 4", "Question 5",
      "Question 6", "Question 7", "Question 8", "Question 9", "Question 10",
      "Question 11", "Question 12", "Question 13", "Question 14", "Question 15",
      "Question 16", "Question 17", "Question 18", "Question 19", "Question 20",
      "Question 21", "Question 22", "Question 23", "Question 24", "Question 25",
      "Question 26", "Question 27", "Question 28", "Question 29", "Question 30",
      "Question 31", "Question 32", "Question 33", "Question 34", "Question 35",
      "Question 36", "Question 37", "Question 38", "Question 39", "Question 40",
      "Question 41", "Question 42", "Question 43", "Question 44", "Question 45",
      "Question 46", "Question 47", "Question 48", "Question 49", "Question 50",
      "Question 51", "Question 52", "Question 53", "Question 54", "Question 55",
      "Question 56", "Question 57", "Question 58", "Question 59", "Question 60",
      "Question 61", "Question 62", "Question 63", "Question 64", "Question 65",
      "Question 66", "Question 67", "Question 68", "Question 69", "Question 70",
      "Question 71", "Question 72", "Question 73", "Question 74", "Question 75",
      "Question 76", "Question 77", "Question 78", "Question 79", "Question 80",
      "Question 81", "Question 82", "Question 83", "Question 84", "Question 85",
      "Question 86", "Question 87", "Question 88", "Question 89", "Question 90"
    ];

  for (var i = 0; i < questions.length; i++) {
    // Check if there is a radio button selected for the current question
    var radioButton = document.querySelector(`input[name="${i + 1}"]:checked`);
    if (radioButton) {
      var answer = radioButton.value;
    } else {
      // Check if there is an input text field for the current question
      var inputField = document.querySelector(`input[name="${i + 1}"]`);
      if (inputField) {
        var answer = inputField.value;
      } else {
        var answer = "Not answered";
      }
    }

    // Wrap the text in cells
    doc.cell(20, 20 + i * 10, 100, 10, questions[i], i);
    doc.cell(50, 20 + i * 10, 100, 10, "Answer: " + answer, i);
  }

  // Save the PDF
  doc.save("Question and answers.pdf");
}
```

I was expecting it will generate not answered if questions are left blank but it is showing as a (option) for this div

```html
<div id="question75" class="question" style="display:none;">
    <p>Question 75</p>
    <div id="answers" class="answers">
      <label>
        <input type="radio" name="75" value="A">
        a
      </label>
      <label>
        <input type="radio" name="75" value="B">
        b
      </label>
      <label>
        <input type="radio" name="75" value="C">
        c
      </label>
      <label>
        <input type="radio" name="75" value="D">
        d
      </label>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: can you clarify what you are asking please

Comment: that and no need for all caps

Comment: i was expecting when i not select any otption (radio) in pdf it will generate not answered but in pdf it is showing me as A instead of not answered

Comment: how to fix that

Comment: You really should learn about `var` and usage of it. You want to define the variable once, not multiple times.

Comment: i made this with chat gpt i dont know coding i am going to learn it soon